# How to alter Services Views result

Tags: views, services

How can I alter [services views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) result. Using services view I can easily produce Json data. 
I have tried [function hook_views_post_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7). This hook is working for simple views but not with services Views(Json data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hook_services_request_preprocess_alter()` and `hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()` hooks of [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.